# Go language - running the same code for multiple select cases

Tags: select, go, channel

Assuming we have multiple notification sources (channels) and we want to perform some similar tasks on some of these notification events. For example, consider the case where we call `doSomething()` every 10 minutes and also upon user request. A possible implementation in Go could be something like this:

```
var ticker = time.NewTicker(10*time.Minute)
nowDoSomething := make(chan time.Time, 1)
for {
    select {
    case <-ticker.C:
        nowDoSomething<-time.Now()

    case <-userReq: // some channel activated occasionally 
        nowDoSomething<-time.Now()

    case <-nowDoSomething:
        doSomething()
    }
}
```

What would be other, perhaps better, ways of achieving a similar functionality?

Comment: `go fmt` is your best friend, please use it.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could do this using the Select function from the reflect package:

> func Select(cases []SelectCase) (chosen int, recv Value, recvOK bool)

Answer (score -3):

Why signaling to yourself using a channel if you can just call doSomething()? I understand do Something might not be exactly a function, but you can always use a local closure.

See a working example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)



func someRoutine (userReq chan int) {
    doSomething := func () {
        fmt.Printf ("OK %v\n", time.Now())
    }

  var ticker = time.NewTicker(10*time.Second)
  for {
    select {
    case <-ticker.C:
        doSomething()
    case <-userReq: // some channel activated occasionally 
        doSomething()
    }
  }
}

func main() {
    userReq := make(chan int, 1)
    go someRoutine(userReq);

    userReq <- 1 // user requested some action here (just to mark the start)
    time.Sleep(15*time.Second)
    userReq <- 1 // user requested some action here

    time.Sleep(30*time.Second)// Put your own waiting and exiting logic here
}
```

If you still want to optimize it beyond this simple correction, there are always some alternatives available. But with just two channels to read from, make sure you're not doing premature optimization.

Comment: Go syntax does not like that. You'll get this error "select cases cannot be lists"